# CPI value at project closure

Tags: budget, evm

What should the CPI be after a project was closed (the project was not canceled)? 
Must the CPI always move to 1 at project closure or could it remain at the last indicated value (example 0.85) before the project was closed?

We had a project and the week before the project was closed the CPI was 0.85. The project is now done and there will be no more work or costs. Should the CPI remain at 0.85?

Answer (score 2):

At completion, your BCWP or EV will equal your BAC.  So your CPI formula will be BAC / CAC (cost at completion).  So, unless your CAC = your BAC, meaning you neither over- nor under-ran your budget, then your CPI will not be 1.00.  Your SPI, however, will be 1.00, which is why is it a useless indicator after the project crosses around the 70% complete threshold.  SPIt, the calculation used in Earned Schedule, is far more accurate and will not yield a 1.00 indication if you are either early or late in delivery.

Answer (score 1):

As @David Espina said, CPI is always derived from the same formula EV/AC. This is true whether the project is closed or not.  What should the CPI be? What is your EV? What is your AC?  The CPI is the ratio of EV to AC.